# How to show color box in select tag in angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular, html, drop-down-menu, angular-material

I need to display a set of color box in select tag dropdown like below.

[image]

I tried it like below

```
<select>
  <option value="">Choose Color</option>
  <option value="red"><div class="color-box" style="background-color: #FF850A;"></div></option>
  <option value="green"></option>
  <option value="blue"></option>
  <option value="yellow"></option>
 </select>
```

But Its not working. Is there any library available for this? Kindly suggest.

Comment: you can't have a div tag inside of <option> tag, inspect the html page and you willl get to know!

Comment: Is there any other way to do that?

Comment: the below answer should work fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is what you are looking for.

*The color of the select box changes to the color of the option selected.*

**APP.COMPONENT.TS**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  selectedColor = '';

  colors = [
    {
      name: 'yellow',
      value: '#ffff00'
    },
    {
      name: 'red',
      value: '#ff3300'
    },
    {
      name: 'blue',
      value: '#0000ff'
    }
  ];

  onChange(value){
    this.selectedColor = value;
  }
}
```

**APP.COMPONENT.HTML**

```
<select (change)="onChange($event.target.value)" [ngStyle]="{'background-color':selectedColor}">
    <option *ngFor="let color of colors" [value]="color.value" [ngStyle]="{'background-color':color.value}"></option>
</select>
```

**Running code:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rzb4rg

Advantages of creating a list in the component itself is that you can add or edit as many options as possible without changing the HTML and this is how we use it in our production also.

Comment: Yes. This is what I was trying to do. Thanks Mate.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `[ngStyle]`

I have create a demo on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/how-to-show-color-box-in-select-tag-in-angular-2?file=src/app/app.component.html)

> component.html

```
<select>
  <option *ngFor="let datas of data" [ngStyle]="{'background-color': datas.color}">{{datas.name}}</option>
</select>
```

> component.ts

```
data=[{
    name:'Red',
    color:'red'
  },{
    name:'green',
    color:'#008000'
  }]
```

Comment: When I select color name. Only color name is displayed. I want to display the color itself in that box.

Comment: Ok let me check

Comment: Krishna Thanks for ur support. But I was looking something like @Shaurya posted.

Answer (score 0):

Just apply your style to the option tag, and it should work as intended :

```
     <select>
      <option value="">Choose Color</option>
      <option value="red" style="background-color: #FF850A;"></option>
      <option value="green"></option>
      <option value="blue"></option>
      <option value="yellow"></option>
     </select>
```

Codepen [here](https://codepen.io/faflo10/pen/jpOMgJ)

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is write the background color for option. See the code below!

```
<option value="">Choose Color</option>
<option style="background-color: #FF850A;" value="red"></option>
<option value="green"></option>
<option value="blue"></option>
<option value="yellow"></option>
```